# ORA-00905: missing keyword (copied from textbook)

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

Have tried looking through the code up-and-down and cannot get it to work. Was mostly trying out the Create table function. Worked fine until trying to create a table with composite primary key. Absolutely stumped. Any help is appreciated.

Tried removing the names for the keys, but then was redirected to a different sort of error: "invalid datatype"

```
Create Table Cust_Artist_EOI    (ArtistID   Number(38)  Not Null,
                                 CustomerID  Number(38)  Not Null,
                                 Constraint  Cust_Artist_EOI_PK Primary Key(ArtistID, CustomerID),
                                 Constraint  Cust_Artist_EOI_ArtistFK Foreign Key(ArtistID)
                                            References  MyArtist(ArtistID)
                                                On Update No Action
                                                On Delete Cascade,
                                 Constraint  Cust_Artist_EOI_CustFK  Foreign Key(CustomerID)
                                            References MyCustomer(CustomerID)
                                                On Update No Action
                                                On Delete Cascade);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `on update`.  Remove that:

```
Create Table Cust_Artist_EOI  (
    ArtistID   Number(38)  Not Null,
    CustomerID  Number(38)  Not Null,
    Constraint  Cust_Artist_EOI_PK Primary Key(ArtistID, CustomerID),
    Constraint  Cust_Artist_EOI_ArtistFK Foreign Key(ArtistID)
        References  MyArtist(ArtistID) On Delete Cascade,
    Constraint  Cust_Artist_EOI_CustFK  Foreign Key(CustomerID)
        References MyCustomer(CustomerID) On Delete Cascade
 );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d80cf0ae905123567f6fdb03b5646395) is a db<>fiddle.

If you look in the [syntax diagram](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52180) for foreign key constraint in Oracle, you will see that neither `on update` nor `no action` is supported.

I'm not sure why `no action` is not supported, because that is the default behavior (and I think it is a good idea to be able to express default behavior).

Not supporting `on update` is a better idea.  It discourages changes to primary keys.  And changing primary keys is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Glad it works now. Any reason why On Update doesn't work?

Comment: @SnappyTurtle . . . Because updating primary keys is a bad idea.  However, I'm not sure why `no action` is not supported.

Comment: Fair enough. Cheers!